# CLI command to remove ActiveMQ topic

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running ActiveMQ on Ubuntu 16.04 and I added a topic by editing the `activemq.xml`. In the broker node I added the following node and restarted activeMQ:

```
<destinations>
  <topic physicalName="topic1" />
  <topic physicalName="topic2" />
</destinations>
```

When I go to my admin panel I can see the 2 topics but now I want to remove `topic 2`. So I removed it from the XML but that does not remove the topic completely. Is there any way how I can remove `topic2` without using java or any other programming language but just CLI commands or by editing some files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ supports automatic destination creation. When you add a queue or topic to the configuration file, it is defining a "static destination"-- a destination that will be there all the time.

If you rely on the auto-creation, the 'delete' destination operation will then work as you are hoping.

A couple options:

1. Don't use any  entries and rely on auto-creation
2. Write some add-edit program to modify the activemq.xml file

Comment: ** Disclaimer: I work for Media Driver ** We created the Integrated Console to help with ActiveMQ administration tasks. It supports remote configuration modification: https://mediadriver.com/software/

Comment: So In my situation where I've cretaed the static destinations already, I can not change it with the the activemq.xml but I should write some program to remove the destinations?

Comment: @SebastienPattyn correct. Generally, most folks just use security <authorizationEntries /> to restrict the destination auto-creation on an app-by-app basis vs use the static defined approach in <destinations />